# How to remove duplicate elements in the " Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers problem"?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

Problem Description: Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

Here is my code:

```
//Class for pairs
public static class Pair{
        int x;
        int y;

        public Pair(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public Pair() {
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "{" +
                    "x=" + x +
                    ", y=" + y +
                    '}';
        }
    }


//function that returns the pairs
public static ArrayList<Pair> twoSum(int[] arr, int target){
        ArrayList<Pair> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length;i++) {
            map.put(arr[i], i);
        }
        for (int j : arr) {
            if (map.containsKey(target - j)) {
                result.add(new Pair(j, arr[map.get(target - j)]));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Sample input: int arr[] = {1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8};
int target = 12;

And the result : [{x=4, y=8},{x=6, y=6}, {x=8, y=4}]

So it works,but i cannot figure out how to remove the duplicates,so for example the 6, 6, pairs.

Comment: if the original array was `1, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8` then would the pair of 6s be considered correct? because I don't see how your map handles duplicate numbers

Comment: Uh, according to the question header, you were asked to return the *indices* of the two numbers. According to the example result, you are returning the elements of the array that can be paired.

Comment: This, or a version of it, is a common problem in programming challenges / practice sites. Can you, please, edit the question to include a link to the web page where you found the problem?

Comment: if (map.containsKey(target - j) && arr[map.get(target - j)] != j)

Comment: @JohnWilliams
Thanks,that's what i was trying to do!

Comment: @Portal
Actually it was not a  coding challenge,i just read this problem in an article,and they didnt mention if it is considered to be correct or not,but i was curious how to remove the 6,6 pair.

Comment: @Geri fair enough, what I was getting at though was that a map may not be the best approach here because of a case like this

Answer (score 1):

> So it works,but i cannot figure out how to remove the duplicates

No...it doesn't work, otherwise you wouldn't have duplicates and, if you don't want duplicates then don't generate and accept them.

Why use Map at all? Just use the ArrayList of Pair (`ArrayList<Pair>`) and two `for` loops, for example:

```
//function that returns the pairs
public static ArrayList<Pair> twoSum(int[] arr, int target) {
    ArrayList<Pair> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = (i + 1); j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == target) {
                /* Uncomment below to Store the 'indices' of the element 
                   pairs that sum to target:     */
                //result.add(new Pair(i, j));
                
                /* Uncomment below to Store the element values of the 
                   element pairs that sum to target:        */
                result.add(new Pair(arr[i], arr[j]));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

To use the above method you might do something like this:

```
int arr[] = {1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8};
System.out.println("Supplied Array:  " + Arrays.toString(arr));
int target = 9;
System.out.println("Supplied Target: " + target);
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Results:");
    
ArrayList<Pair> pairs = twoSum(arr, target);
System.out.println(pairs);
```

Results to Console Window:

```
Supplied Array:  [1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8]
Supplied Target: 9

Results:
[{x = 1, y = 8}, {x = 4, y = 5}, {x = 3, y = 6}]
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by changing the type of `result` to the interface, `List<Pair>`, and the method return type accordingly. Program to the interface (if one exists). As to why use a map, one might argue that a lookup is preferred to two for loops with somewhat complex index calculations. For each number, you lookup one value (e.g., if total is _9_, and _a = 1_, lookup _8_; if not there, move on) rather than iterating through all remaining values. But really, half a dozen of one, 6 of another.

Comment: One reason for using a `Map` is performance. For this problem, nested loops typically run in O(n^2) time. But, good use of a `Map` can be used for a solution that runs in O(n).  By the way, I like that your code showed how it can be modified to return indices or element values.

Comment: Thanks everyone!
@OldDogProgrammer Yes,thats the reason i went with the map.I am new to coding,and was trying to play with the hashmap and see how it works.